# Error message: No primary or single unique constructor found for interface jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, aws-lambda

I have built a spring boot application with several rest apis. I am deploying this application on aws lambda with the help of `SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler`.

Getting **`Error`** `message: No primary or single unique constructor found for interface jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest` when i hit the desired endpoint.

Following is the handler:

LambdaHandler.java

```
package com.testapp.api;

import com.amazonaws.serverless.exceptions.ContainerInitializationException;
import com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.model.AwsProxyRequest;
import com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.model.AwsProxyResponse;
import com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.spring.SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler;

public class LambdaHandler implements RequestHandler<AwsProxyRequest, AwsProxyResponse> {
    private static SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler<AwsProxyRequest, AwsProxyResponse> handler;

    static {
        try {
            handler = SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler.getAwsProxyHandler(TestApplication.class); }
        catch (ContainerInitializationException ex){
            throw new RuntimeException("Unable to load spring boot application",ex); }
    }

    @Override
    public AwsProxyResponse handleRequest(AwsProxyRequest input, Context context) {
        return handler.proxy(input, context);
    }
}
```

UserController.java

```
package com.testapp.api.controllers;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.testapp.api.dto.formatter.GetCurrentUserFormatterDto;
import com.testapp.api.services.users.GetCurrentUserService;

import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class UserController {
  
  @GetMapping("/current")
  public ResponseEntity<String> GetCurrentUser(HttpServletRequest request) {

    return ResponseEntity.ok().body("Test");
  }
}
```

On hitting the endpoint:
I am getting the following error:

**Error** message: No primary or single unique constructor found for interface jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest

After searching for a while, I came to know that I might be because of the way lambda handles requests and response using `AwsProxyRequest` and `AwsProxyResponse`. These objects are not directly convertible to `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse`. I want a way handle these requests using `HttpServletRequest` in my controller. I have tried using `jakarta.servlet-api` with version = 6.0.0, but the issue still persists.

Comment: Why are you trying to deploy a Spring app as a Lambda function? There are better ways to deploy a Spring app on AWS such as using AWS Fargate and containers.